# Is it true that if the anticanonical divisor has positive self-intersection then it is ample?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I think it is a true statement, since the anticanonical divisors of del Pezzo surfaces have positive self-intersection number, and they are ample. But my professor told me it's wrong. Can someone tell me if it is true?

Comment: Why didn't you ask your professor why it is wrong? Anyway, it _is_ wrong. If $-K_X$ is nef and big, it will have positive self-intersection number, but it need not be ample. The simplest example is to blow up 3 points on a line in $\mathbf P^2$.

Comment: I would say that a del Pezzo surface by definition has ample anticanonical class. And the blowup of 3 points on $\mathbb{P}^2$ is not a del Pezzo surface.

Comment: @Sasha: I agree with both your sentences. My understanding is that the question the OP was asking is the question in the title. In particular they were not asking just about del Pezzos.

Comment: He said he wanted me to find out the correct statement. thank you Nefertiti and Sasha!